# Intercepting SOAP service using JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, soap

Since we know the fact that REST services can be used with SOAP ones, is there a way to intercept SOAP services using Jax-RS. I got both REST/SOAP services running in my system and I need to have some sort of interceptor to intercept the service calls. I can easily intercept the REST calls using JAX-RS but not the SOAP services.

Has anyone gone through this kind of situation, please let me know.

Comment: Just because it is somehow possible does not mean it does make sense! SOAP and REST only share in common that both typically are built on top of HTTP whose feature they use more or less.

Comment: I agree but do you recommend any way to achieve what I am looking for. I need to log the request/response as a pre/post processor.

Comment: Well, technically SOAP sends almost all messages through HTTP POST (SOAP 1.2 does allow to send GET messages as well but this is even more ugly in terms of HTTP operations than sending everything via POST). What your server-side routine does with the received request is totaly in your hands. If you want to be able to process these SOAP messages, you need to parse the SOAP envelope (header + body) and invoke the respective method at your service and return a proper SOAP response with status code 200 or 400 back to the client

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by exposing your SOAP web services as Camel end points.  Then you can use camel to 'log the request/response as a pre/post processor'.  There are lost of articles on the subject- here is an example of exposing your SOAP WS via [Camel](https://dzone.com/articles/exposing-and-consuming-soap).

Comment: IMO [Apace CXF](http://www.javatips.net/blog/expose-cxf-service-with-rest-and-soap), which Camel also uses for SOAP support (at least if you added its dependencies), does provide pre/post-processing logging for both SOAP and REST messages, would probably be closer to the OPs need.

Comment: CXF is implied but I should have said it explicitly. Thanks for pointing that out.